# Is there a way for me to crop in the middle of a video to run my vehicle detection model on that part

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I want to run inference of my vehicle detection model only on the center of a video. like you see in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xyx3R.png). The red zone is only where I want my model to run. I wanted to know if there's a way for me to do that. to specify a zone for my model to work.

Comment: You can create a mask that allows only the central portion of the frame to be visible but blacks out the rest.

Comment: I have no idea what you use but usually modules get frame from video as numy array and it is easy to crop array. `array[start_row:end_row , start_col:end_col]`. But frankly, all depends on your code which you didn't show.

Comment: I still did not write a code I just wanted to know if it's a possibility. I'm gonna right one now and I will post it after I'll finish it

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I have used for the crop which kinda works. I  just need to implement it with my vehicle detection model which I will post right after I finish

```
# Import packages
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Open the video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.mp4')

# Initialize frame counter
cnt = 0

# Some characteristics from the original video
w_frame, h_frame = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)), 
int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fps, frames = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

# Here you can define your croping values
x,y,h,w = 0,0,600,1000

# output
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')

#fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'XVID')

out = cv2.VideoWriter('result.mp4', fourcc, fps, (w, h))


# Now we start
while(cap.isOpened()):
ret, frame = cap.read()

    cnt += 1 # Counting frames

# Avoid problems when video finish
if ret==True:
    # Croping the frame
    crop_frame = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # Percentage
    xx = cnt *100/frames
    print(int(xx),'%')

    # Saving from the desired frames
    #if 15 <= cnt <= 90:
    #    out.write(crop_frame)

    # I see the answer now. Here you save all the video
    out.write(crop_frame)

    # Just to see the video in real time          
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('croped',crop_frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
else:
    break


cap.release()
out.release()  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```